# Как менять цвет svg

Tags: javascript, svg

У меня есть картинка, как при помощи js менять fill-opacity с 0.4 до 0.9 , то есть , если в переменной допустим стоит 50 , то закрашены будут половина полосочек , если 100 , то будут закрашены все полосочки?

```css
body {
   background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="64" height="24" viewBox="0 0 64 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <rect x="59" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 59 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="52.5" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 52.5 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="46" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 46 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="39.5" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 39.5 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="33" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 33 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="26.5" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 26.5 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="20" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 20 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="13.5" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 13.5 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.4"/>
         <rect x="7" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 7 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.4"/>
         <rect x="0.5" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 0.5 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.4"/>
      </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно выбрать все `rect` с помощью [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), затем пробежаться по ним в цикле и выставить нужный атрибут.

Установить атрибут можно с помощью [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

1. первый параметр - имя атрибута
2. второй - значение

Например

```
.setAttribute('fill-opacity', 0.4)
.setAttribute('fill-opacity', 0.9)
```

```js
function change(val) {
  document.querySelectorAll('rect').forEach((r, i) => r.setAttribute('fill-opacity', i < val ? 0.9 : 0.4));
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#o {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<output id="o">7</output><input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="7" step="1" oninput="change(this.value); o.value=this.value" />
<svg width="64" height="24" viewBox="0 0 64 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <rect x="59" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 59 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="52.5" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 52.5 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="46" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 46 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="39.5" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 39.5 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="33" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 33 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="26.5" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 26.5 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="20" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 20 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.9"/>
         <rect x="13.5" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 13.5 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.4"/>
         <rect x="7" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 7 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.4"/>
         <rect x="0.5" y="23.25" width="22.5" height="4.5" rx="2.25" transform="rotate(-90 0.5 23.25)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.4"/>
      </svg>
```

Comment: Да , работает замечательно , только не понял как задать атрибута через setAttribute ?

Comment: @Дмитрий, добавил пояснение, пример вызова есть в самом коде.

Comment: когда я указываю или 0,4 или 0,9 , при сдвиге ползунка , все полосочки окрашиваются , а как сделать так , чтобы я мог при помощи переменной задать , какое количество полосочек будет закрашено ?

Comment: @Дмитрий, не понял что ты делаешь. В примере ты закрываешь столько полосочек, сколько выбрано в ползунке.

Comment: Ну я правильно понял , что надо так писать ? 
document.querySelectorAll('rect').forEach((r, i) => r.setAttribute('fill-opacity', 0.9)); Просто мне надо , чтобы именно я допустим указал переменной там пускай val = 5 - это будет означать , что будет закрашено 5 полосочек из 10 , задал val = 2 , будут закрашены 2 из 10 полосочки

Comment: @Дмитрий, сейчас функция `change` принимает значение и закрашивает столько, сколько передали